# Java Implicit super() call recursion

Tags: java, constructor, super

While I do not have an error, or any code on the matter due to my inexperience, the implicit call to `super()` in a child class's constructor has confused me.

If I am calling the constructor of a child, whose parent is also a child, etc. will there be a **series of consecutive** `super()` calls? As in, since the parent constructor also has an implicit call to `super()` will that call be made?

And if so, **how deep can that go**/how deep does it go?

I apologize if I have been confusing or asked an obvious question, my instructor didn't provide a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Why not write the code and test it?

Comment: The implicit calls to `super()` go all the way up to the top `java.lang.Object`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Constructor chain

> will there be a series of consecutive `super()` calls?

Yes, that is exactly what happens. Each time you construct an object in Java, so `new Foo()`, it will first go up the **full inheritance tree** and start constructing the *parents* from top to bottom.

So if you have a setup like

```
class Chihuahua extends Dog { ... }
class Dog extends Animal { ... }
class Animal { ... }
```

and construct an instance of the `Chihuahua`

```
new Chihuahua()
```

Java follows up the chain of inheritance and calls the parent constructors in the following order

1. Object
2. Animal
3. Dog
4. Chihuahua

Before an object can be constructed, Java first has to construct its *parent base*.

---

### `Object` - the end of inheritance

> And if so, how deep can that go/how deep does it go?

It always goes up the full inheritance tree. Which always ends with the *all-father-class* `Object`. Either by explicitly extending it

```
class Foo extends Object { ... }
```

or by implicitly exending it, if you do not write anything

```
class Foo { ... }
```

`Object` is a special class, it has no further parents and marks the end of each inheritance chain.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will accept this answer when I am allowed to do so.